# Proof that there's a unique linear transformation for every n by m matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix.  Let $B$ be a basis for an m-dimensional vector space $\Bbb U$.  Let $C$ be a basis for an n-dimensional vector space $\Bbb V$.  Prove that there is a unique linear transformation $f: \Bbb U \to \Bbb V$ with $[f]_{CB}=A$.

So I think I have a proof that $f$ exists:
Let $B=\{\mathbf b_1, \mathbf b_2, ... , \mathbf b_m\}$ and $C=\{\mathbf c_1, \mathbf c_2, ... , \mathbf c_n\}$.
Construct $f$ as follows:  Given $A \in M_{n \times m}$, let $A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1m}\\
        a_{21} & a_{22} & ... & a_{2m}\\
        \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
        a_{n1} & a_{n2} & ... & a_{nm}\\
        \end{bmatrix}$.

Let $f(b_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} \mathbf c_i$.
Because $B$ is a basis for $\Bbb U$, we can express an arbitrary vector $\mathbf u \in \Bbb U$ as $\mathbf u = \sum_{j=1}^m u_j \mathbf b_j$.
Thus $A[\mathbf u]_B = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \sum_{j=1}^m a_{1j} u_j\\
        \vdots\\
        \sum_{j=1}^m a_{nj} u_j\\
        \end{bmatrix}$,
$\left[ A[\mathbf u]_B \right]_i=\sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij} u_j$

And
$f(\mathbf u) = f(\sum_{j=1}^m u_{j} \mathbf b_j) = \sum_{j=1}^m u_{j} f(\mathbf b_j) = \sum_{j=1}^m u_{j} (\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} \mathbf c_i)$.

Therefore $\left[f(\mathbf u)\right]_i = \sum_{j=1}^m u_j a_{ij} =  \left[ A[\mathbf u]_B \right]_i$

So $f$ exists for any arbitrary $\mathbf u \in \Bbb U$

I'm probably missing some stuff in there for proper rigor, but that seems to work.
But how do I then prove that this $f$ is *unique*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $g$ was another such transformation with matrix representation as $A$. Then see what will be $g(\mathbf{b_i})$ where $\mathbf{b_i} \in B$. Once two linear transformations agree on a basis then they will agree everywhere else.